# Look up functions for multiple cells and matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am trying to lookup a value when two columns are the same. To start, I have a drop down menu. The users selects which item name they want and when they click it, it enters into cell H26. Next, I have a table. There are 4 columns : NAME, LOGIC, TITLE to DISPLAY, VLOOKUP.

Cells E39-E43is the NAME column.  So pretty much when the user select from the drop down menu an item list those being Modules 1-7, Modules 8-12, etc., the label gets inserted into cell H26. The Logic column has an IF statement that will either put “1-7”, “8-12”, etc. or leave it blank.

I am using the Title to Display column to reference. Below is the table. I am trying to use the vlookup column and in one cell be able to lookup and match when a cell in the Logic column matches the cell in the Title to display. When a match occurs, I need the value, whether its 1-7, 8-12, 13-16 etc. Can this be accomplished using one cell and with the least complicated logic. The front end program doesn’t respond well to perplexed and elongated excel functions. Thank you for your time
[image]

Comment: So if the first cell in LOGIC is `1-7`, you want `1-7` in the VLOOKUP column. If `17-13` is in the 4th cell, you want `17-23` in the VLOOKUP column. If all cells are blank in LOGIC, you want a blank. If there are more than one cell in LOGIC that matches TITLE to Display, you want the first match. LOGIC cannot contain something else than blank that doesn't match TITLE to Display. Are all those right?

Comment: Thanks for your response, there wont be more than one cell in LOGIC that matches. Since the drop down menu selects only one option, h26 has only one value. This means that the LOGIC column is either all blank  or it has one field that has the values indicated in the IF statement. I am merely trying to grab whatever that displays in the LOGIC column. Did this answer what you are inquiring about in your response? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as per what you mentioned, you can actually use a simple `VLOOKUP` formula with an approximate match lookup mode:

```
=VLOOKUP("zz",F39:F42,1)
```

I'm assuming that your range of LOGIC is within F39:F42. The above formula normally returns only the last non-blank text value (at least, one that is alphabetically before `zz`) from the given range. The above is equivalent to:

```
=VLOOKUP("zz",F39:F42,1,TRUE)
```

OR

```
=VLOOKUP("zz",F39:F42,1,1)
```

They are the same thing, but when you omit the last parameter, excel defaults to `True` (or `1`)

---

EDIT: I overlooked the fact that there won't actually be blanks in the range F39:F42, but empty strings left behind from the `IF`. For small number of rows, you can concatenate all the strings together:

```
=F39&F40&F41&F42
```

For larger sets of data, you might have to resort to an array formula:

```
=INDEX(F39:F42, MATCH(1,--(F39:F42<>""),0))
```

Invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: When I use the "zz" I am getting blank. I need "1-7", or "8-12" or "13-16" to appear. Is the reason why mine isn't working like how your setup suggests because its not recognizing the value "1-7" as text?

Comment: @ENGR024 Oops. I didn't test the formula under the conditions that you were having it... You will actually notice that it works only if the last module is selected, and that's because a blank from `""` in the IF is not a real blank. Hmm, the second simplest formula I believe would be `=F39&F40&F41&F42` (i.e. concatenating all the cells together. Only one will have a value and the rest will be empty strings. Of course, that might be a bit difficult to adapt for many lines, so I'm not sure if that works for you here. Do say so otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second option you suggested works for this  particular project. please see the link below ....http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx     the limit is 255 text strings. This means a combination of how ever many cells but the combination of all is limited to 255 characters or 2^8.? is this right? I don't know if this will work on an upcoming project that will have more items.. it may though. but for now it works perfect. thanks for your help and everyone else's.

Comment: @ENGR024 I added a formula for larger sets of data. I didn't want to use one for something that looked as simple as this, but I guess that can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

What i have understood is that you want to match the H26 Value with H39:H42 and if match is found, you want numeric portion of the Data validation to be displayed in VLOOKUP cell. If that description is correct you can simply use this:

`=TRIM(MID(H26,8,999))`

...assumes that it will always be a six character word Module in the beginning. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried putting this in the vlookup cell  but am getting I've entered too many arguments for this function. Are you suggesting to bypass the LOGIC column and in the vlookup obtain the values directly? If so, I can't use this. These are specific conditions that go along with the titles that are being selected by the user. There are other titles that I didnt put on here that are on the drop down list but don't need to obey or have nothing to do with the IF statements. I just need the values from the titles that DO meet the specific conditions. e.g. Modules 1-7.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, logically there is no need for look-up table, but it could be desirable if extracting numeric portion is intricate enough. Thank again.